# Single arrow node with fixed, text-independent dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to have several single arrow nodes all with the same dimensions (independent of the node text). I tried to achieve this by setting `minimum width`, `minimum height`, `inner sep`, and `single arrow head extend`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{MyArrow/.style={single arrow, draw, minimum width=6ex, minimum height=10ex, 
                         inner sep=0ex, single arrow head extend=1ex}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[step=1ex,gray,ultra thin] (-1ex,-4ex) grid (45ex,4ex);
        \path (0,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a1) {};
        \path (a1.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a2) {a};
        \path (a2.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a3) {b};
        \path (a3.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a4) {bg};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here, the arrow dimensions depend on the text.
[image]

One can indirectly make the arrow dimensions independent of the node text by using `\rule` as the node text and adding the text with a subsequent command:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{MyArrow/.style={single arrow, draw, minimum width=6ex, minimum height=10ex, 
                         inner sep=0ex, single arrow head extend=1ex}
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[step=1ex,gray,ultra thin] (-1ex,-4ex) grid (45ex,4ex);
        \path (0,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a1) {\rule{0ex}{4ex}};
        \path (a1.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a2) {\rule{0ex}{4ex}};
        \path (a2) node {a};
        \path (a2.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a3) {\rule{0ex}{4ex}};
        \path (a3) node {b};
        \path (a3.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a4) {\rule{0ex}{4ex}};
        \path (a4) node {bg};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I was wondering whether there is an easier way to directly determine the dimensions of the single arrow node shape and make it independent of the node text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use dimensions in `ex` and `em` then they are subject to change. Use absolute dimensions like `mm` or `cm` or `in`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{MyArrow/.style={single arrow, draw, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=30mm,
                         inner sep=0mm, single arrow head extend=1mm}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[step=1ex,gray,ultra thin] (-1ex,-4ex) grid (45ex,4ex);
        \path (0,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a1) {\strut};
        \path (a1.south) ++(0,-10mm) node[MyArrow] (a2) {\strut a};
        \path (a2.south) ++(0,-10mm) node[MyArrow] (a3) {\strut b};
        \path (a3.south) ++(0,-10mm) node[MyArrow] (a4) {\strut bg};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have used `\strut` to maintain height and depth of the text. You can use `text height` and `text depth` instead. Put them in `mm` too.

Comment: Don't use `minimal` even if it's in the OP's question.

Comment: @ egreg: May I ask you why in your opinion `\documentclass{minimal}` is not a good choice for code examples?

Comment: @Robert see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided).

Answer (score 3):

Your first example fails because you use `inner sep=0ex`. With this option commented out, the first arrow keeps `minimum width` and `minimum height`.

Once you have decided minimum height and width, you can simulate writing some contents inside arrows with the `label=center:...` option instead of using `{...}`. In this case, label's text is written on node's center.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{MyArrow/.style={single arrow, draw, minimum width=6ex, minimum height=10ex, 
                         %inner sep=0ex, 
                         single arrow head extend=1ex}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[step=1ex,gray,ultra thin] (-1ex,-4ex) grid (45ex,4ex);
        \path (0,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a1) {};
        \path (a1.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow, label=center:a] (a2) {};
        \path (a2.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow, label=center:b] (a3) {};
        \path (a3.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow, label=center:bg] (a4) {};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There was another answer (which disappeared in the meantime) mentioning the node parameters text height and text depth. I think setting these could solve my problem...

Comment: You can change the order of the keys too.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I wanted to have a an arrow with a fixed `single arrow head extend` and a fixed width of the arrow tail. For this, setting the parameters `text height` and `text depth` do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Harish Kumar's hint to to set `text height` and `text depth` I came up with the following solution.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{MyArrow/.style={single arrow, draw, minimum width=5ex, minimum height=10ex, 
                         inner sep=1ex, text height=1ex, text depth=0ex,
                         single arrow head extend=1ex}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[step=1ex,gray,ultra thin] (-1ex,-4ex) grid (45ex,4ex);
        \path (0,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a1) {};
        \path (a1.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a2) {a};
        \path (a2.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a3) {b};
        \path (a3.east) ++(1ex,0) node[anchor=west,MyArrow] (a4) {bg};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

resulting in the following output.

[image]